# im trying to work on a quiz app in react that i got from freecodecamp but when i try to start it throws me an error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

i downloaded starter code for a quiz app in react from github and in the dependencies the script to start is "react-scripts start" at first when i ran it with npx it said i needed to download the react-scripts package then i did that but now when i run npx react-scripts start i get

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/start-scripts - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'start-scripts@latest' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2022-08-19T17_59_32_170Z-debug-0.log
(base) Users-MacBook-Pro-5:starter user$ npx react-scripts start
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'react'
Require stack:
- /Users/user/.npm/_npx/cd53aabf71f3f793/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/.npm/_npx/cd53aabf71f3f793/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:43:31)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/user/.npm/_npx/cd53aabf71f3f793/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js'
  ]
```

Comment: Did you run `npm i` in your terminal before starting the app?

Comment: i did that and now it is up and running so whenever i grab other peoples project files i need to run npm install before to run it locally?

Comment: Yeah for projects that has a `package.json`.